# Kotlin cannot cast to Integer

Tags: kotlin

```
var num = pref?.getInt("something", 1)
```

This gives me `"java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer, null"`

However I don’t see a long here. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning what API this is...

Comment: Can you show us what `pref` is? Especially the `getInt(String, Int)` method...

Comment: SharedPreference

Comment: It says `num` is null, but wherever you're passing it expects non-null value.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce How is it null though? In case “something” was null then 1 is returned

Comment: If `pref` is null, then it will return `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"pref" contains Long class may be

you should try

```
var num = pref?.getLong(“something”,1L)
```

Comment: I don’t want long, I want an int

Comment: @JoeRobert if you store a `Long` you should also retrieve a `Long`... from there on you could still do something like `Long.toInt()`... but depending on what long this is, you shouldn't transform it to an `Int` ;-)

Comment: How am I storing a long? .getInt returns an int

Comment: Look for calls which set preferences (probably something like `putInt`/`putLong`/etc.)

Comment: You were right Alexey! For some reason Flutter’s sharedPref putInt is actually putLong. They should have just named putLong instead of confusing the shit out of me. Thanks man!

Comment: This is the root of the problem （putInt/putLong/etc.）